# PHP WordPress - Advanced Custom Fields - Applying Filters in Pro version

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a WP plugin and have integrated ACF (free version) as per the documentation on their website: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/

I also use a series of filters to load the ACF fields based on the location setting:

```
$this->loader->add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_types', $plugin_admin, 'acf_location_rules_types' );
$this->loader->add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_values/cpt', $plugin_admin, 'acf_location_rules_values_cpt' );
$this->loader->add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_match/cpt', $plugin_admin, 'acf_location_rules_match_cpt', 10, 3 );
```

This code is based on this simple plugin: https://github.com/lukechapman/custom-post-template-support-for-acf/blob/master/acf-custom-post-template-support.php

Everything has worked absolutely perfectly, but since I have upgraded to ACF pro this has completely stopped working.

I can't seem to find any resources specific to adding filters for ACF pro, only the basic version. I've debugged it and can confirm paths are correct, no errors in logs, and I also added some debug code to the first callback function `acf_location_rules_types()` and this is not being called at all.

The script that loads the filters is working, but it's like the filter options no longer exist in ACF Pro.

Where am I going wrong with this?

**EDIT**

I've also tried a very simple implementation like this which is also not being called:

```
add_filter('acf/location/rule_types', function ($rules) {
    error_log('acf/location/rule_types debug');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-update_value/

Comment: I have updated new one please try this one

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// functions.php
add_filter('acf/location/rule_types', 'acf_location_rules_types');
function acf_location_rules_types( $choices ) {
    $choices['Post']['post-type-has-taxonomy'] = __('Post Type has Taxonomy');
    return $choices;
}
add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_values/post-type-has-taxonomy', 'acf_location_rules_values_has_taxonomy' );
function acf_location_rules_values_has_taxonomy( $choices ) {
    return array_merge($choices, get_taxonomies());
}
add_filter('acf/location/rule_match/post-type-has-taxonomy', 'acf_location_rules_match_has_taxonomy', 10, 3);
function acf_location_rules_match_has_taxonomy( $match, $rule, $options )
{
    if ($rule['operator'] == '==') {
        $match = is_object_in_taxonomy($options['post_type'], $rule['value']);
    } elseif ($rule['operator'] == '!=') {
        $match = !is_object_in_taxonomy($options['post_type'], $rule['value']);
    }
    return $match;
}
```

Comment: This is what I have tried. The callback isn't being called.